# Angular mat diaglog wait for response

Tags: angular

From my angular app, i am opening a Dialog service (first dialog) and performing some operation.

After completing the operation, user select to save the operation.

While saving the operation, want to display a confirmation message (second dialog...Implemented using Mat-Dialog).

In Confirmation message, user can select either Yes or No.

When user select No, i should close the second dialog alone...

But the issue is, after opening the second dialog, first dialog also getting closed without waiting for the confirmation message.

Code in the first dialog:

```
onCommitChanges(errors) {

  if (errors.length > 1) {
    this.openSecondDialog(errors[1])
  }

  //visibilit flag of p-model.      
  this.displayFunctionEditor = false;
}
```

Code in the second dialog:

```
openSecondDialog(errorMessage: string) {      
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialog, {
      data: {
        message: errorMessage,
        buttonText: {
          ok: 'Continue',
          cancel: 'Cancel'
        }
      }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
      if (confirmed) {
      }
    });
}
```

After calling second diaglog, want to wait for confirmation...

Could you please help me to resolve this

Regards

Comment: Just as a hint. Opening a dialog with a dialog is bad user experience and usually should be avoided if possible. You probably have other options with `*ngIf` to do it so.

Comment: Make sure disableClose option of the dialog are enabled

Comment: Resolved the issue using promise...But the problem is seconds window is not in focus....could you please help me to resolve this